# Windows 8 Side-Bar Not Appearing

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui

Bringing the mouse to the bottom right hand corner of the screen does absolutely nothing. I am not really sure how I can expand on this - it used to work and now it simply doesn't, and I can't think of any reason why.

Comment: are you referring to charms bar?

Comment: @nEwgUy am not sure of the exact name, but the one which comes up when you move the mouse to the bottom right, with the search, share, start, devices and settings buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bringing the mouse to the bottom right hand corner of the screen indeed does absolutely nothing. I used to have this problem, then I discovered that it was actually my method of opening the charms bar that was wrong:

1. Try bringing your mouse to the bottom right corner and slowly(**while the mouse is at the rightmost**), bring the mouse up.
2. Bring mouse to the top right corner and slide down while **keeping to the right.**

Comment: This worked - which is interesting, because it always used to work via just putting the mouse in the bottom right hand corner... Has there been a change at some point?

Comment: No I think it might be because you 'think' you're just putting your mouse to the corner, but actually it also moves a bit up too which shows you the charms bar, or at least that's what happened in my case. I had to check out the Win8 tutorials to know that you actually had to slide the mouse vertically not just putting it in the corner when it happened to me. Glad that your problem is solved anyway :)

Comment: Maybe - I'm quite surprised it's taken me well over a year of having Windows 8 to find out though

Comment: Yeah there's also the possibility of an update that changed it too... Anyway if it doesn't work you can also use Win+C to access to charms bar :)